# Plot producing many error messages when given complicated function

Tags: plotting, evaluation, syntax

I'm new to *Mathematica* and am running in to all sorts of silly difficulties with coding in it. I'm trying to calculate a function `f[x, k]`, normalise it with another function `n[k]` and then calculate and plot a thrid function `en[k]` that depends on the first two. Unfortunately, *Mathematica* won't plot it, and I can't see what I did wrong. I'm sure it's a trivial mistake on my part and I'm sorry to have to ask. Here's my code:

```
L = 8;
f[x_, k_] := 
  Cos[Pi k/(2 L)]^2  Exp[(-(x - k)^2)/2] - Sin[Pi k/(2 L)]^2 (x - L) Exp[(-(x - k)^2)/2];
n[k_] := Integrate[f[u, k]^2, {u, -L, L}];
en[k_] := Integrate[f[v, k] (-f''[v, k] + (v - k)^2  f[v, k]), {v, -L, L}]/n[k];
Plot[en[k], {k, 0, L}]
```

Comment: I think you should specify the derivation variable in `f''[v,k]`

Comment: Thanks, that did it. You deserve a kiss.

Comment: You don't mention the nominated kisser, but I'll take that as a compliment at any rate.

Answer (score 2):

First, as Belisarius points out, you need to indicate the variable for your second derivative. You also need to carry out your differentiation and integrations before you try to plot `en[k]` Also, please look at the help that is provided [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/), especially the discussions of the difference between `=` and `:=`.

```
L = 8;
f[x_, k_] :=
  Cos[Pi k/(2 L)]^2 Exp[(-(x - k)^2)/2] - Sin[Pi k/(2 L)]^2 (x - L) Exp[(-(x - k)^2)/2];
n[k_] = Integrate[f[u, k]^2, {u, -L, L}];
d2f[v_, k_] = D[f[v, k], {v, 2}];
en[k_] = Integrate[f[v, k] (d2f[v, k] + (v - k)^2 f[v, k]), {v, -L, L}]/n[k];
Plot[en[k], {k, 0, L}]
```

[image: plot.png]